# How do I set up patches randomly in netlogo, BUT not have them touch each other?

Tags: installation, netlogo, patch

I am trying to set up my patches so that they do not touch each other, but are randomly placed.

Right now with the code below, they set up with the scale color how I would like, but not randomly placed:

```
to setup-patches
  ask n-of number-of-patches patches
  [ ifelse neighbors4 = green
    [ set pcolor black ]
    [ set quality (random 10)
    set pcolor scale-color green quality 0 10] ]
```

Any help on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to make use of the `any?` and `shade-of?` primitives, to have each patch check whether any of their neighbors have not just the color green, but any shade of green. Also note that if you do `random 10` to set quality, then patches will have a quality anywhere from 0 to 9, as NetLogo's `random` is not inclusive. Therefore, you may want to scale your quality a little differently for visualization (as in the example below).

```
patches-own [ quality ]

to setup
  ca
  ask n-of 400 patches [ 
    ifelse any? neighbors4 with [ shade-of? pcolor green ] [ 
      set pcolor black 
    ] [ 
      set quality 2 + random 7
      set pcolor scale-color green quality 0 10] 
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

Gives you something like:

[image]